# Is it possible to save a Diablo 3 chat session or save some in game notes

Tags: diablo-iii

I'd like to take some in-game notes, for example significant items I sold at the AH (with links to the items), some tips or various things I want to remember, etc.

For instance by sending chat messages to myself and saving the log somehow.

Is that possible?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just interested in saving the items you've sold on the Auction House, would not a screenshot work just as well as a note? Simply highlight the item and press PrtSc (by default) and Diablo 3 will snap a picture of whatever you've currently got open.

You could even use this to take screencaps of your chat logs, though you wouldn't be able to click on any links therein.

Pictures go into your C:/Documents/Diablo 3 folder by default (assuming you're on Windows).

Comment: Thanks I know, there is also a trick in the auction house to see the specs of the object AFTER it has been sold, in the Completed list (open a chat and shift+click on the gold icon, enter then click on the object link in the chat).

I wanted something in-game without having to alt+tab constantly...

Comment: @SemMike Unfortunately, Diablo 3 doesn't support anything like that. :/

Comment: Ok thanks, maybe something for another patch, along with the annoying problem of the game not remembering many (but not all, strangely) key bindings after every log out...